# Hangfire - new server appears every time code changed

Tags: hangfire

I'm new to Hangfire. I have it working on a dev machine but every time I change the code and run the app (asp.net Core 2 MVC) - a new server appears in the list on the dashboard.

I can't find anything in the documentation about this - or in the sample files. I've read about cancellation tokens but these seem to be for intentional shutdown requests not code updates?!

Is this expected behaviour? Am I expected to manually restart the application in IIS every time code is updated (more important on the server than dev machine obviously).

Thanks.

Comment: Facing the same problem at the moment.. did you find any solution to it?

Comment: I found they tend to just go away by themselves after not too long?!

Comment: Thanks - Yeah looks like they are timing out or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Found a work around @ this [link](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/handling-long-running-tasks-long-invisibility-timeout-server-restarts/989/13) which worked for me. Credit to ihockett.

**TLDR**

> I know this is a pretty old topic at this point, but I’ve been running into a similar issue. I wanted to throw my contribution to working around jobs which have been aborted due to server shutdown. If automatic retries are disabled (Attempts = 0), or the jobs fails due to server shutdown and is beyond the maximum number of attempts, you can run into this issue. Unfortunately for us, this was causing new jobs to not start processing until the aborted jobs were either manually deleted or re-queued.
>
> Basically, I took the following approach to automatically handle aborted jobs: during startup and after initializing the BackgroundJobServer, I use the MonitoringApi to get all of the currently processing jobs. If there are any, I loop through each and call BackgroundJob.Requeue(jobId). Here’s the code, for reference:

```
var monitor = Hangfire.JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();                
if (monitor.ProcessingCount() > 0)
{                    
    foreach (var job in monitor.ProcessingJobs(0, (int)monitor.ProcessingCount()))
    {
        BackgroundJob.Requeue(job.Key);                        
    }
}
```